# IP Address Restriction

Tags: iis-7, ip, address, restriction

I need some technical help regarding IP address restriction in IIS7. My problem how i can block all IP's except following IP address ex:- 69.59.196.212 in my IIS7. I want give access max 4-5 IP's remaining all Block.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

See [Configure IPv4 Address and Domain Name Allow Rules (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731598%28WS.10%29.aspx) in the [IIS 7 Operations Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732976%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

1. In **IIS Manager**, click on **IP Address and Domain Restrictions**.
2. Click **Edit Feature Settings** in the Actions panel.
3. Choose **Deny** from the list, and click OK.
4. Click **Add Allow Entry** and add IP addresses and/or ranges.
5. In this way all unknown IP addresses will be forbidden.